# Problemas al usar el modulo fs y path con electro, vite, y react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, electron, vite

en estos momentos me encuentro teniendo un problema bastante raro.
Quiero leer un archivo .txt pero al usar los modulos path y fs, me tira un error y se rompe todo.
Aca les dejo el codigo a ver si me pueden echar una mano, se los agradezco mucho.

Este es el modulo vite.config.ts

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import electron from 'vite-plugin-electron';
import renderer from 'vite-plugin-electron-renderer';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import { resolve } from 'path';


Este es el vite.config.ts

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        tsconfigPaths(),
        electron([{ entry: 'electron/main.ts' }]),
        // renderer(),
    ],
    // resolve: {
    //  alias: {
    //      src: resolve('src/'),
    //      '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    //      '*': resolve(''),
    //  },
    // },
    server: { port: 3000 },
});
```

Y aca les dejo donde quiero leer el archivo

```js
import * as fs from 'node:fs';
import * as path from 'node:path';
// import documento from './doc/credential.txt';

export const credentialMagnament = () => {
    const ruta = path.resolve(__dirname, 'doc/credential.txt');

    // console.log(ruta);
    fs.readFile(ruta, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                console.error('myfile does not exist');
                return;
            }
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Por favor pega el error.

Comment: @eventHandler El error dice esto
uncaught error: dynamic require of "path" is not supported